# How can I make digital sum function using classes

Tags: python, class, recursion

We just started learning python this year in school, and so far we are only doing basic stuff with tkinter canvas (drawing houses, flowers etc.) and our teacher kinda sucks so I had to learn everything I know by now myself.

I've been thinking about this idea of writing a function to find the digital sum of a number (without recursion preferably) so I came up with this:

```
def sum(n):
    total=0
    for letter in str(n):
        total+=int(letter)
    return total
```

But then, I had an idea about using recursion to find the "absolute dig. sum of a number", for instance 99=9+9=18 =>1+8=9
and I came up with this

```
total=0
def suma(n):
    global total

    def part_sum(n):
        global total
        total_part=0

        for letter in str(n): 
            total_part+=int(letter) 
        total=total_part 

        if total<10:
            print(total)
        else:
            part_sum(total)

    part_sum(n)
```

which basically makes a sum of n, checks if it is lower than n, if it is not it runs it again (basic recursion), but it uses a bunch of variables and global variables (which are for some reason bad as I've heard) and I am well aware it could be done much more efficiently using classes and objects, but I've only watched couple of vidoes on that so I'm not very good at it.

Could someone please edit my code and paste it here with some notes to help me understand it?

Comment: I'm sorry, you wrote that code and you want us to help you understand it? Help you understand the working piece of code that you wrote....

Comment: ```...could be done much more efficiently using classes and objects...``` -you need to realize that in python everything is an object including a function. [The Standard type hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy). A function works fine for this task.

Comment: [Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#classes).

Comment: Edit your code how?

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is often overused. I believe you can write `suma()` much more clearly without it. Build on what you have already created.

```
def sum(n):
    total=0
    for letter in str(n):
        total+=int(letter)
    return total

def suma(n):
    while n >= 10:
        n = sum(n)
    return n
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution

```
def rec_dig_sum(n):
    total = str(sum(map(int, str(n))))
    while len(total)>1:
        total = str(sum(map(int, total)))
    return int(total)
```

You can think of `map` as taking `map(function, [input1, input2, input3])` and returning `[function(input1), function(input2), function(input3)]`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving a variable and updating it with each iteration of a loop (the normal way to do this):

```
def iterative_sum(num):
    while num >= 10:
        num = int(sum(map(int, str(num))))
    return num
```

Send it as an argument to a new function call:

```
def recursive_sum(num):
    if num >= 10:
        return recursive_sum(sum(map(int, str(num))))
    return num
```

You can also make a recursive function to do the initial summation, and use that in the function that keeps doing so until it's only one digit:

```
def rc(n, c=0):
    if n:
        return rc(n//10, c+n%10)
    return c

def rs(n):
    if n >= 10:
        return rs(rc(n))
    return n
```